# How to handle if a particular API call doesn't return any data i.e. empty json objects?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using react.js and Axios to call a particular API which I created myself.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

class Orders extends Component {

    //To Store bunch of orders
    state = {
        orders : []
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {

     axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/order/findOrdersByUsername/12345`)
        .then(res => {
            const orders = res.data;
            this.setState( { orders });
            console.log(res.data);
        })
    }

render() {

const show = () => {

if(!this.state.orders) {
  return <>No orders</>;
}
}

return (
<>
{show()}
</>
);

}

}

export default Orders;
```

Basically I want to show users that there are no data for this record. However it fails and it pretends there is some sort of data in it.

Comment: What does it displays?

Comment: If I call the show function, it doesn't show anything. However I am trying to show that there are no orders at the moment.

Comment: Check for the length of the array. Like ` this.state.orders && this.state.orders.length > 0`

Comment: You better add a ` .catch ` block for axios in case you want to handle server-side errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the value of `orders` is defined or not. Instead, you should check if an element exists or not.

```
if(this.state.orders.length === 0) {
  return <>No orders</>;
}
```

Comment: @ucoder21 Glad to help. Please upvote the answer and mark it as correct